# How do you prevent a rich text box from automatic scrolling, when performing syntax highlighting?

Tags: c#, user-interface, scroll, richtextbox

- Language = C#
- .NET version = 3.5

When my code performs syntax highlighting the text appears, to the user, to be scrolling automatically. This becomes a severe problem when there is several hundred lines of text in the rich text box. So, how can I programmatically modify the text's color without causing the user to see anything other than the color change?

Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: Could you explain how you are performing syntax highlighting? I would like to implement this feature in a product I'm working on myself. Cheers.

Comment: My algorithm currently contains six steps. 
1) Remember the current position of the caret.
2) Disable updates to the text box.
3) Search for text that needs highlighted.
4) Highlight the text with the appropriate color.
5) Repeat steps 3 & 4 until all text that needs highlighted is highlighted. 
6) Set the caret's position to its correct position.

This algorithm is needs some work. It is slow on large amounts of text. However, only highlighting the text the user sees should fix the performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Save selstart position. 
Disable updates to the text box.  
Apply syntax highlighting.
Set selstart to saved value.  
Enable updates.
```

Comment: I did everything except disable updates and enable updates. Now that I did that it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: I recognized the problem, even though I don't speak C#, having been there myself.